# Unable to simulate invoking applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:?

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter

Here is the calling code:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification
                                                    object:[UIApplication sharedApplication]];
```

It can not invoke `applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:` from `UIApplicationDelegate`.

Anything wrong?

Comment: Is that delegate method not being called? I've seen a lot of examples make the notification name a string, such as @"UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification". I doubt that really matter thought because that constant is probably the same thing.

Comment: Even changed to NSString, it can not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot simulate a memory warning by posting a notification. The `UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification` is posted *by* `UIApplication` when it receives a memory warning, but it doesn't observe it, and therefore doesn't call your view controllers' `didReceiveMemoryWarning:` method when you post such a notification manually.

As Rob already pointed out though, you can simulate a memory warning in the iOS simulator by using the "Simulate Memory Warning" menu item.

You could also observe the notification in your view controllers, instead of implementing `didReceiveMemoryWarning:`, but I wouldn't recommend that, because the behavior of system-supplied view controllers might be different when you fake a memory warning that way.

Answer (score 2):

In the simulator, use the menu to trigger a low memory warning.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What should work is using `UIApplicationMemoryWarningNotification` instead of `UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"UIApplicationMemoryWarningNotification"
        object:[UIApplication sharedApplication]];
```